# How do I disable a button in an ng-include when a form in a sibling ng-include is $invalid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The idea is disable the 'Submit Me' button when form 'myForm' is invalid. I tried searching but all of the examples are within the form.  Can someone shed some ideas on how to do this?

Note: The button I want to disable is outside the form, buttons within the form will be disabled.

EDIT Additional: the form in being added using ng-include and the button is added using a separate ng-include. Sorry for not adding this detail maybe this is the reason it does not work in my case.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7BY2kwciERqQLNGfcDtz <--- this is working now.

Form.html

```
  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="myText" type="text" ng-model="mytext" required />
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>
  </form>
```

Button.html

```
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit Me</button>
```

HtmlBody:

```
  <body>
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'form.html'"></div>
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'button.html'"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Because this works just fine [here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6aZkRuZdkJ6Vu4nZwqpW?p=preview)

Comment: In fact, here's [your exact code copied and pasted into a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0dWtftUicEbtibpou97n?p=preview). It works fine.

Comment: Okay, so the current case i'm having is that that the <form> is being added by ng-include.

Comment: I've added a plnkr of an ng-included button and form

Comment: The plnkr is working for me... did you change it? Or is it not locked?

Comment: The plunkr has been updated and it's working as expected now. I added an answer below with that plunkr as an example. As you've noticed the problem is the ng-include creating child scopes. See plunkr for more info if you've experienced this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what i did was create a parentForm using ng-form so I can access the child scopes produced by ng-include. See the plunkr for more information.

I have added this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7BY2kwciERqQLNGfcDtz

Comment: You should add the code example here in case Plnkr goes down. For the next person with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch the validity of a given form in your controller and update a scope value based on that:

```js
$scope.$watch('myForm.$valid', function(newVal) {           
  $scope.myFormValid = newVal;
});
```

Then on your button:

```html
<button ng-disabled="!myFormValid">Submit Me</button>
```

Comment: Adding another $watch to the $digest for no discernible benefit isn't a good idea... especially when there's no problem to be solved with this question. The OP must not have tried his code, because it works fine as is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. I did try this code but i missed the case where i have included those snippets using ng-include. Maybe this is the reason it does not work on my end.

Comment: This answers the first question before the edit. So I upvoted this one. Helped me realize the real problem which is the ng-include produces child scope. Also this one.

Comment: Since the OP question has changed... fairly drastically, I've changed my vote. I'm still not a fan of adding $watches in controllers, however.

Answer (score 1):

You break the form logic by putting the submit button outside de form.

However, I copy/pasted your html code in a jsfiddle and it worked fine without any change. The submit button is disabled when the field is empty.

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LAeeF/

I just added a basic controller :

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        alert('Submit button enabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a plunkr to simulate my case.

Comment: This answers the first question before the edit. So I upvoted this one. Helped me realize the real problem which is the ng-include produces child scope.